# Too many indices for array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a 3D image mat1 from the data given to me by an object. But I am getting the error for the last line: `mat1[x,y,z] = mat[x,y,z] + (R**2/U**2)**pf1[l,m,beta]`:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

What could possible be the problem here?

Following is my code :

```
mat1 = np.zeros((1024,1024,360),dtype=np.int32)

k = 498
gamma = 0.00774267
R = 0.37
g = np.zeros(1024)
g[0:512] = np.linspace(0,1,512)
g[513:] = np.linspace(1,0,511)
pf = np.zeros((1024,1024,360))
pf1 = np.zeros((1024,1024,360))

for b in range(0,1023) :
  for beta in range(0,359) :
    for a in range(0,1023) :
      pf[a,b,beta] = (R/(((R**2)+(a**2)+(b**2))**0.5))*mat[a,b,beta]
    pf1[:,b,beta] = np.convolve(pf[:,b,beta],g,'same')

for x in range(0,1023) :
  for y in range(0,1023) :
    for z in range(0,359) :
        for beta in range(0,359) :
         a = R*((-x*0.005)*(sin(beta)) + (y*0.005)*(cos(beta)))/(R+    (x*0.005)*(cos(beta))+(y*0.005)*(sin(beta)))
          b = z*R/(R+(x*0.005)*(cos(beta))+(y*0.005)*(sin(beta)))
          U = R+(x*0.005)*(cos(beta))+(y*0.005)*(sin(beta))
          l = math.trunc(a)
          m = math.trunc(b)
          if (0<=l<1024 and 0<=m<1024) : 
              mat1[x,y,z] = mat[x,y,z] + (R**2/U**2)**pf1[l,m,beta]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line where you do the [convolution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html):

```
pf1 = np.convolve(pf[:,b,beta],g)
```

generates a 1-dimensional array, and not 3-dimensional as your call in the last line: `pf1[l,m,beta]`

To solve this you can use:

```
pf1[:,b,beta] = np.convolve(pf[:,b,beta],g,'same')
```

and you also need to predefine pf1:

```
pf1 = np.zeros((1024,1024,360))
```

Note that the convolution of *f*g* (`np.convole(f,g)`) returns normally a length of *|f|+|g|-1*. If you however use [`np.convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) with the parameter `'same'` it returns an array which has the maximum length of f or g (i.e. *max(|f|,|g|)*).

**Edit:**
Furthermore you have to be sure that the dimensions of the matrices and the indices you use are correct, for example:

You define `mat1 = np.zeros((100,100,100),dtype=np.int32)`, thus a 100x100x100 matrix, but in the last line you do `mat1[x,y,z]` where the variables x, y  and z clearly get out of these dimensions. In this case they get to the range of the `mat` matrix. Probably you have to change the dimensions of `mat1` also to those:

```
mat1 = np.zeros((1024,1024,360),dtype=np.int32)
```

Also be sure that the last variable indices you calculate (l and m) are within the dimensions of `pf1`.

**Edit 2**: The [`range(a,b)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function returns an array from a to b, but not including b. So instead of `range(0,1023)` for example, you should write `range(0,1024)` (or shorter: `range(1024)`).

**Edit 3**: To check if `l` or `m` exceed the dimensions you could add an error as soon as they do:

```
      l = math.trunc(a)
      if l>=1024:
          print 'l exceeded bounds: ',l
      m = math.trunc(b)
      if m>=1024:
          print 'm exceeded bounds: ',m
```

**Edit 4**: note that your your code, especially your last `for` will take a long time! Your last nested for results in 1024*1024*360*360=135895449600 iterations. With a small time estimation I did (calculating the running time of the code in your for loop) your code might take about 5 days to run.

A small easy optimization you could do is instead of calculating the sin and cos several times, create a variable storing the value:

```
sinbeta = sin(beta)
cosbeta = cos(beta)
```

but it will probably still take several days. You might want to check how to optimize your calculations or calculate it with a C program for example.

Comment: I tried pf1[:,b,beta] = np.convolve(pf[:,b,beta],g) but it still gives the same error.

Comment: See the answer, I've changed it.

Comment: Thanks! I don't get that error now. But now I get  mat1[x,y,z] = mat[x,y,z] + (R**2/U**2)**pf1[l,m,beta]

IndexError: index 1024 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1024

Comment: From the error I understand the variable `l` gets to value 1024 which is out of bounds since `pf1`'s first dimension is 1024 long (i.e. has index 0 to 1023).

Comment: Even when I initialize : for x in range(0,1025) I get the same error.

Comment: No, you should not increase the x range if you don't change the dimensions of the matrix. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: Yes. I changed it to 1024,1024,360. Yet the same error. You can see my edited code above.

Comment: Did you check if the l and m variables do not exceed the dimensions of `pf1`?

Comment: When I try to find out len(l) or len(m), they say that object of type 'int' has no len(). Does it convert to an integer because of truncating a and b? I actually want the final equation to have a and b only. But because the indices should be integers, hence the truncation.

Comment: l and m are scalars, and I referred to the values of them which should not exceed the dimensions of pf1, in this case 0<=l,m<1024.

Comment: When I print m and l, the four for loops run and I keep getting values of l and m. So there are 1024*1024*360 values each of l and m. And hence when it does not go with the final equation as the dimensions of l and m should be only 1024.

Comment: So I made the edit according to your suggestion (above in the code) but now it has been running since infinite time without any error or results.